# Printing an object's toString not behaving as expected

Tags: android

I have tried to print a variable value but this is what was printed:

`android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintEditText@41fb6428`

My code is:

```
Torre objTorre = new Torre();

objTorre.setLatitude(txtLat.toString());

String torre =  objTorre.getLatitude();

System.out.println(torre.toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just do this

```
objTorre.setLatitude(txtLat.getText().toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line to:

```
 objTorre.setLatitude(txtLat.getText().toString());
```

To get the text from your EditText and not the reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

`getLatitude()` returns an instance of `android.support.v7.internal.widget.TintEditText`, which AFAIK is a subclass of `EditText`.

If you are trying to get at what the user typed into the `EditText` as a `String`, call `objTorre.getLatitude().getText().toString()`.